# Windows universal доступ к папкам

Tags: c#, uwp

Создал проект по шаблону windows universal, в классе System.Environment отсутствует свойство CurrentDirectory, т.ею я не могу получить доступ к рабочему каталогу. Есть ещё варианты получения доступа к рабочему каталогу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно Вам подойдет данный метод - Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Comment: CurrentDirectory — это не «рабочий каталог», это «каталог, откуда запустили программу» (и при этом он не обязан совпадать с «каталогом, в котором программа лежит»). Вам почти никогда не должно быть нужно значение CurrentDirectory. Скорее всего, у вас баг.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UWP работают в песочнице, там много чего нет, из того, что доступно обычному приложению. Если Вам нужно получить доступ к содержимому песочницы, Вы должны использовать [ApplicationData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241587) класс. У него есть статическое свойство `Current`, посредством которого Вы можете получить доступ к базовым папкам: local, temp, roaming и т.п.